# How to fix the Gradle Plugin Error with Android project build?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.5.3

Error message :

Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in. The minimum supported version is x.x.x Please update the version of the dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In Android Studio, select File ---> Settings ---> Gradle ---> Project-level settings ---> select "Use default Gradle wrapper (recommended)" ---> Apply ---> OK.

2) Visit the link below for choosing the correct Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version accordingly and update the same in File ---> Project Structure.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions

4) File ---> Sync Project with Gradle Files. This will download the required files and fix the error.